# list wasn't removed correctly using list.remove() method

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Binary Watch](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-watch/description/)
I was trying to get all the valid set through the following approach. However my `all_comb` still includes result such as `[8, 4, 2, 1, 0.32, 0.16, 0.08, 0.04, 0.02, 0.01]`

It seems my check function only removes part of the list that contains 
`[8,4]` and `[0.32, 0.16, 0.08, 0.04]`

I've been stuck on this for a while. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`

```
upperLst = [8, 4, 2, 1]
lowerLst = [0.32, 0.16, 0.08, 0.04, 0.02, 0.01]
lst = upperLst + lowerLst
```

`

```
`def all_com(lst, num):
    new_lst = []
    for l in range(len(lst) + 1):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(lst, l):
            new_lst.append(list(subset))
    return new_lst
def remove(lst):
    """Check if the lst is the valid combinations"""
    upper = all(x in lst for x in [4, 8])
    lower = all(x in lst for x in [0.32, 0.16, 0.08, 0.04])
    return upper or lower or False
def check(lst):
    """check all the combinations are valid"""
    for l in lst:
        print("not removed lst", l)
        if remove(l):
            print('removed list: ', l)
            lst.remove(l)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you loop through a list as you modify it, you mess up the order of iteration. I ran the following example on the interpreter:

```
 list = range(10)
 for val in list:
    print val
    list.remove(val)
```

The output was 0 2 4 6 8, and not 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 .

You could fix this by appending the valid combinations to a list and then returning that list, so that you don't modify the original list.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense!! I changed `for l in lst[:]` and it works!! Thanks a lot!!